# Archiving AWS RDS mysql Database

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, amazon-glacier

I am looking for options to archive my old data from specific tables of an AWS RDS MySQL database.
I came across AWS S3, AWS Glacier and copy the data to either one using some Pipelines or Buckets, but from what I understood they copy the data to vault or backups the data, but don't move them.

Is there a proper option to archive the data by moving from RDS to S3 or Glacier or Deep Archive? i.e., deleting from the table in AWS RDS after creating an archive.
What would be the best option for the archival process with my requirements and would it affect the replicas that already exist?

Answer (score 6):

The biggest consideration when "archiving" the data is ensuring that it is in a useful format should you every want it back again.

Amazon RDS recently added that ability to [export RDS snapshot data to Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/01/announcing-amazon-relational-database-service-snapshot-export-to-s3/).

Thus, the flow could be:

- **Create a snapshot** of the Amazon RDS database
- **Export the snapshot** to Amazon S3 as a Parquet file (you can choose to export specific sets of databases, schemas, or tables)
- **Set the Storage Class** on the exported file as desired (eg Glacier Deep Archive)
- **Delete the data** from the source database (make sure you keep a Snapshot or test the Export before deleting the data!)

When you later wish to access the data:

- **Restore the data** if necessary (based upon Storage Class)
- Use Amazon Athena to **query the data** directly from Amazon S3

Comment: How do you restore that data back into RDS? As it is no longer a "RDS snapshot", will you have to use something like Glue and/or DMS?

Comment: @jbernal If you are intending to restore the data into RDS, I would recommend using RDS snapshots. The other steps (suggested above) are for storing the data _outside of_ RDS.

Comment: Yes, but imagine you need (for compliance reasons) to keep snapshots for, say, 5 years and you want to save some cost by moving them to cold storage. If you ever move them outside RDS after 3 months to achieve this saving (S3), how you could restore that snapshot should you ever need it?

Comment: Not sure, but I would recommend that you **test** to make sure it works! Most databases have an export format that can be used to reload. I'm a PostgreSQL person and I know that the `pg_dump` command produces output that can simply be run via an SQL client to recreate the database. I do not know the MySQL equivalent.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I ended up recommending, EC2 to run ´pg_dump´ and ´pg_restore`. That way, backups can easily be stored in S3 and Glacier and restore back to RDS if needed. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason of keeping the whole DB snapshot if youi want to acrhive only some data from specific tables?

Comment: @GinoPane The above steps recommend exporting data from the Snapshot to S3. Yes, you could then delete the Snapshot but first make sure you have tested the export to make sure you aren't going to lose any data.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I did build a similar pipeline using AWS lambda that runs on a cron schedule(Cloudwatch event) every month to take a manual snapshot of the RDS, export it to S3, and delete the records that are older than n days

I added a gist of the util class that I used, adding it here if it helps anyone
[JS Util class to create and export Db snapshots to S3](https://gist.github.com/Murali91/8a767d4f39a921b78ee09a39e7461377)

PS: I just wanted to add it as a comment to the approved answer but don't have enough reputations for that.